# Replacing array value PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex, php-7

i want to change the last "S" letter in array value. i've try many ways but still wont work.

here's my code ():

```
<?php
$array = array ("romeo/echos/julion/1991s/1992.jpg",
                "romeo/echos/julion/1257s/1258.jpg",
                "romeo/echos/julion/1996s/1965.jpg",
);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == "romeo/echos/julion/'.*?'s/'.*?'.jpg") 
         $value="romeo/echos/julion/'.*?'l/'.*?'.jpg";
}

print_r($value);
?>
```

i want the value look like this :

```
Array ( [0] => romeo/echos/julion/1991l/1992.jpg 
        [1] => romeo/echos/julion/1257l/1258.jpg 
        [2] => romeo/echos/julion/1996l/1965.jpg
      )
```

Comment: I haven't checked your regex, but the point is you can't apply a regex using `==` and a substitution by assigning a value containing a regex. You can get rid of the `if` and use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$value` is a copy of the array element, so assigning to it doesn't modify the array. If you use a reference variable it will update the array.

Also, you're not testing the value correctly. First, you're using `==` when you should be using `preg_match()` to test a regular expression pattern. And you're testing `$key` instead of `$value` (the keys are just indexes `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.)

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    if (preg_match('#(romeo/echos/julion/.*?)s(/.*?.jpg)#', $value, $match)) {
        $value = $match[1] . "l" . $match[2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the following and it provides the exact output you would like.

```
$array = array("romeo/echos/julion/1991s/1992.jpg",
            "romeo/echos/julion/1257s/1258.jpg",
            "romeo/echos/julion/1996s/1965.jpg");

$replace = str_replace("s/1", "l/1", $array);
    print_r($replace);  
}
```

outputs :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => romeo/echos/julion/1991l/1992.jpg 
    [1] => romeo/echos/julion/1257l/1258.jpg 
    [2] => romeo/echos/julion/1996l/1965.jpg 
)
```

Comment: Please read question carefully.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone  Answer fixed :)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone better ?

Comment: Bad form, just copying from mine.

Comment: huh? copy from your what ?

Answer (score 0):

use `str_replace()`

```
  <?php
    $array = array ("romeo/echos/julion/1991s/1992.jpg",
                    "romeo/echos/julion/1257s/1258.jpg",
                    "romeo/echos/julion/1996s/1965.jpg",
    );

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

      $arr[]=str_replace('s/1','l/1',$value);
    }

    print_r($arr);
    ?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => romeo/echos/julion/1991l/1992.jpg [1] => romeo/echos/julion/1257l/1258.jpg [2] => romeo/echos/julion/1996l/1965.jpg )
```